# Historgram x-axis divisions in R

Tags: r, histogram

I have a data set involving financial loans. One of the columns is "Amount Requested," and another column is "Amount Funded."  The two sets are pretty closely matched. By that I mean, same essential ranges, means, and so on. And the histograms look almost identical.

The problem I'm having is that when I run the histograms side by side, the x-axis on the "Amount Requested" divides up into the following: 0, 5000, 15000, 25000, 35000. It extends to the far right of the histogram.

But the x-axis on the "Amount Funded" divides up into a different set: 0, 10000, 20000, 30000. And it stops noticeably shorter than the end of the histogram.

I've looked at the histogram parameters and can't seem to figure out how to homogenize the two ranges.

Comment: You want `breaks`. Easiest thing to do is set it as a single number representing the number of breaks. But you could also run something like `quantile` or `cut` on the original data and then use that as the break points in both plots.

Comment: @Thomas, I have tried using breaks. They seem to work on the data and the number of bins, but not the structure of the x-axis itself.

Comment: You might need to supply your data (e.g., using `dput`) so that the problem is reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The "Amount Funded" data set had two rows with slightly out-of-range values at the lower end. In other words, rather than "0.00" being the amount funded, the two rows had "-0.01". Once I accounted for that (i.e., removed those rows), the two histograms aligned perfectly.